# how to get the sizes of files in an online directory?

Tags: apache, web, terminal, fileserver

I've looked everywhere for an answer but I couldn't find anything. I need to get the list of all the files and their sizes in a directory such as http://example.com/files/ without downloading the files. Directory listing is enabled on the server and I can see all the files if I click on the link. Is it also possible to list only the files bigger than 1 mb and search any subdirectories as well?

Comment: If directory listing is enabled (and the `SuppressSize` option isn't set), then the listing will contain the size, so request the listing somehow (`curl`, a perl script, Ajax in JavaScript, etc.) parse out the size, and skip any files smaller than 1mb.

Comment: Can you provide such script?